# hierarchical models and m:m/matrix relationships

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

I have a still rudimentary understanding of hierarchical models so please bare with me. The standard text book example uses a tree/hierarchical structures like this:

```
schools -> classes -> pupils
```

Here we have a proper hierarchical/tree 1:m relationship (e.g. a school will have many classes but a class only belongs to one school and a class can have many pupils and a pupil belongs to only one class).

Can hierarchical modeling also be used for matrix/m:m relationships? Made up example:

```
business section <-> office location
```

An international business is divided into various sections and the sections can have satellite office in different locations, which in turn can host serval business section of the same business.